# How to customize the header in TexMaker (Latex)?

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr, includegraphics

I'm trying to make a header in Texmaker, but when I compile the header is on top of the initial part of the rest of the document (article). Also how can I align a logo on the left side as two line text centered on the right side with some distance from the header line? I used this in the preamble but it doesn't work:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\begin{tabular}{c}
{\Large First Title} \\
{\large Second title}
\end{tabular}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}
```

Comment: (1) Please always supply a complete example document (Minimal Working Example-MWE). (2) Look into your log file, it will tell you how to adjust the header height. (3) How do you want to align the logo with the text? Please supply a drawing of the required header.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how you want your header, I'll give it a try.

- Look into your log file, it will tell you how to adjust the header height. It will look something like

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 87.3565pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{87.3565pt}.
(fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller:
(fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-75.3565pt}.
```

The numbers will be different depending on the size of your logo and text. I've used rounded numbers:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{88pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-76pt}
```

I use `\makecellbox` from the package `makecell` to do the alignment.
I have code included both for vertically centered alignment and top-alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\setlength{\headheight}{88pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-76pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% This is for the image and text to be vertically centered:

\rhead{\makecellbox{{\Large First Title} \\ {\large Second title}}}
\lhead{\makecellbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}\vspace{2pt}}}

% Use this to have them top-aligned:

% \rhead{\makecellbox[t]{{\Large First Title} \\ {\large Second title}}}
% \lhead{\makecellbox[t]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}\vspace{2pt}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Center alignment:

[image]

Top alignment:

[image]